# How to make child div ( positioned absolute ) overflow a parent div which is positioned relative having overflow:auto?

Tags: jquery, html, css, overflow

So my code is something like this:

```html
<div style="position:relative; width:500px; border:4px solid yellow; height:300px; overflow:auto;">
  <div style="position:absolute; width:400px; border:4px solid black;height:500px; z-index:1000;" />
</div>
```

I must not modify the specified styles and I cannot add extra html elements.
I can use only new css attributes or jquery/javascript.

Please help :)

Comment: Well, if you can't override the **overflow** (causing the issue), you can't move/add the extra elements, you (i'm guessing) don't want to edit the overflow using jquery, there isn't much we can do.

Comment: my college teacher wants me to do this

Comment: If I was you and I was given a load of inline styling, I'd be looking for a new teacher.

Comment: I thought so... well I will have a long talk with my teacher then... thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relatively-positioned parent is designated the [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#containing-block-details) of the absolutely-positioned child. As a result, the absolutely-positioned child is subject to the `overflow` property of its parent. See the spec on [overflow control](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#overflow).

You cannot do anything to change this behavior as long as the element with `overflow: auto` is the containing block of the absolutely-positioned element (i.e. as long as all of these things are true simultaneously). You could use jQuery to detach the child from its parent and put it outside, but you would then have to account for its new position with respect to, say, the viewport.